# How can I filter a list in Java using a predicate function?

Tags: java, generics, collections, contravariance

Consider the following code:

```
ICondition searchCondition, scopeCondition...
List<ICondition> filtered = CollectionUtil.filter(
    Arrays.asList(searchCondition, scopeCondition),
    CollectionUtil.isNonNull);
```

It fails to compile:

> "The method `filter(Collection<T>, CollectionUtil.Predicate<T>)` in the type `CollectionUtil` is not applicable for the arguments `(List<ICondition>, CollectionUtil.Predicate<Object>)`"

Everything is fine if I define an `ICondition`-specific `isNonNull()` predicate, but that's dumb and I don't understand what's wrong or how to fix it.

Here are my utility functions:

```
public interface Predicate<T> 
{
    boolean apply(T type); 
}

public static <T> List<T> filter(Collection<T> target, Predicate<T> predicate) 
{
    target = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(target);
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T element: target) {
        if (predicate.apply(element)) {
            result.add(element);
        }
    }
    return result;
}


// This predicate works as expected.
public static CollectionUtil.Predicate<String> isStringNonBlank = new CollectionUtil.Predicate<String>() {
    public boolean apply (String item) {
        return !StringUtils.isBlank(item);
    }
};

// This predicate looks fine, but fails in usage.
public static CollectionUtil.Predicate<Object> isNonNull = new CollectionUtil.Predicate<Object>() {
    public boolean apply (Object item) {
        return null != item;
    }
};
```

Why can't I use the second predicate with `filter()`?

Comment: Not sure, but try changing isNotNull to return <? extends Object>.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your `filter` function's `predicate` parameter is not properly *contravariant*. Try rewriting it as follows:

```
public static <T> List<T> filter(Collection<? extends T> source,
                                 Predicate<? super T> predicate)
{
  final List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>(source.size());
  for (T element: source)
    if (predicate.apply(element))
      result.add(element);
  return result;
}
```

That says that so long as the predicate function is willing to accept a type no *narrower* than type `T`, calling it with an instance of type `T` (or some type further derived from `T`) will work fine.

Comment: +1, my answer fixes the OP's direct problem and the general case but really the filter method doesn't need to accept an exact `Predicate<T>` as you say.

Comment: Thank you both. I was worried at having just typed that out without having compiled either your example or my proposed solution, but apparently the idea was sufficient. Please do come back and note whether it works out as written.

Answer (score 2):

Try generifying `isNonNull`:

```
private static class IsNonNullPredicate<T> implements Predicate<T> {
    public boolean apply(T item) {
        return null != item;
    }
}
```

Now you can return it through a generic method in your util class instead of a constant.

```
public <T> Predicate<T> isNonNull() {
    return new IsNonNullPredicate<T>();
}
```

Alternatively, just do an unchecked cast on a stored instance instead of creating a new one each time:

```
private final Predicate isNotNullPredicate = new IsNonNullPredicate();
public <T> Predicate<T> isNonNull() {
    return (Predicate<T>) isNotNullPredicate;
}
```

This is what the `Collections` class in the Java Collections library does to provide support for generics in its utility methods.  Before 1.5 there was `Collections.EMPTY_LIST` which after generics were added would return a `List<Object>`.  However, that wouldn't give back a suitably generified list so `Collections.emptyList()` was added to return a `List` of any type that would fit the calling context.

Comment: thanks, im pretty sure this will work too, i would like to think i would have arrived here after an hour away from the computer!